# SELinux interfering with host/guest file sharing using KVM

Tags: fedora, kvm, selinux

I'm running Fedora 17 with KVM and the virtual machine runs okay. I tried to follow [this](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio) to get access to a file on the host system but SELinux prevents the VM from accessing any files other than those in `/var/lib/libvirt/images`. This is the message the host gives when running `ls` inside the VM on the shared path.

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/qemu-kvm from read access on the
directory share.
```

How can I get around this? The purpose of my VM is to test binaries on multiple Linux distributions so a shared path would be easiest. Is there a way to make /tmp/share absolutely accessible by everyone?

Comment: Besides changing the file context (which is ultimately the best answer) you can either switch SELinux to permissive (if you're not serving to the broader network I mean), or do an `audit2allow` which will automatically generate the SELinux policy changes that will allow the operations currently being denied.

Answer (score 4):

The destination share (you didn't give the path qemu is trying to access) should have the  `svirt_image_t` security context (can be verified by doing `ls -ldZ <pathToDestination>`). If this is labelled as something else SELinux will not let kvm read/write on that dir.

Solution is to do the following (replace <pathToDestination> with the actual path):

```
semanage fcontext -a -t svirt_image_t "/<pathToDestination>(/.*)?"
restorecon -vR <pathToDestination>
```

The above sets the default file context for anything under and including pathToDestination, the second command tells SELinux to restore file contexts on everything underneath that directory to what we have as being the default (i.e what semanage changes).

You can also check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for possible reason for the AVC denial

Search for the AVC denials of today
`/sbin/ausearch -m avc -ts today`

Or check `/var/log/messages` It will tell you the unique identifier for the AVC denial which needs to be run as an argument to `sealert -l`

Example:
    sealert -l 84e0b04d-d0ad-4347-8317-22e74f6cd020

You have to go through that information. It tells the commands you need to execute to overcome AVC denials.